# Issue with storing inputs from HTML form into jquery vars

Tags: jquery

Again, very new to programming, and starting down jquery and ajax.  I have been able to use jQuery without too much issue, but now I am wanting to extend to ajax to forumate API calls based on user input.  In the snippet below, I have pasted the section of the jquery handler for the form submit.  If I console.log the various inputs within the jquery function (.val()), I see values.  If I attempt to create a value in the function, and set it to the .val() of the input, I get undefined.  What stupidity am I stuck in?

section of jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#user_in").submit(function() {

            var city=$(city).val();
            var state=$(state).val();
            var year=$(year).val();
            var month=$(month).val();
            var day=$(day).val();

            console.log(city);  //returns undefined
            console.log($(city).val()); //returns the form submission

                  <div id="form_div">
                    <form id="user_in" action="index.html" method="post">
                            <p>Please enter your city name:</p><input type="text" name="city" id="city"><br>
                            <p>Please enter your two letter state:</p><input type="text" name="state" id="state"><br>
                            <p>Please enter the year of history (YYYY):</p><input type="text" name="year" id="year"><br>
                            <p>Please enter the month (MM ):</p><input type="text" name="month" id="month"><br>
                            <p>Please enter the day (DD):</p><input type="text" name="day" id="day"><br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML ? It seems that your selectors are wrong

Comment: Share your HTML code so we can help you on how to get the value from your HTML elements

Comment: grrrr.  I don't know this interface yet.  How do I input the html code without it being rendered?

Comment: Paste your HTML code to the editor then, highlight your HTML code and press the **{ }** icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I don't know how your HTML look like, but i suggest you have a look at you elements and there id or class.

If city, state, year, month and day are id of elements your code should look like this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {

        var city=$('#city').val(); //gets you the value from an element with id="city"
        var state=$('#state').val();
        var year=$('#year').val();
        var month=$('#month').val();
        var day=$('#day').val();

        console.log(city);  
        console.log($('#city').val());
})
```

If the names are classes then change # to . in every jQuery call.

Answer (score 2):

Based from your `input` element, you can get it's value using jQuery through this

`var city = $('#city').val();`

This basically means that you're getting the `input` value by it's `id` attribute.

Or you can also do it this way:

`var city = $('input[name="city"]').val();`

Which basically means that you're getting the `input` value by it's `name` attribute

Answer (score 1):

Since you have shared your `HTML`, try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("form").submit(function() {

        var city=$("#city").val();
        var state=$("#state").val();
        var year=$("#year").val();
        var month=$("#month").val();
        var day=$("#day").val();

        console.log(city);  //returns undefined
```

I strongly recommand you to read about this page about [**jQuery Selectors**](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)